# Python Loading Screen

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, simultaneous

I'm making a program like isup.me to check if a website is down. I'm trying to make it print "Searching..." until it's found the status code for the website, but not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

```
import requests
import time

website = input("Website to check: ")
if "http://" in website or "https://" in website:
    pass
else:
    website = "{0}{1}".format("http://", website)

def print_screen():
    printing = "\nSearching...\n"
    for letter in printing:
        print(letter, end="")
        time.sleep(.005)
    print()
def requesting():
    try:
        user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)             
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
        r = requests.get(website, timeout=10, headers = user_agent)
        print("Website status code: ", r.status_code)
        status = r.status_code

        while True:
            if status in range(400,599):
                if status in range(403,404):
                    print("Website is up and running!")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Website is down :( ")
                    break
            else:
                print("Website is up and running!")
                break

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
        print("Website timed out, either your connection is extremely slow, or the website is down")

def main():
    print_screen()
    requesting()

main()
```

Comment: You need to trigger the request in a separate thread and update shared variable once it's done.

Comment: how would you do this?